# how to get all contacts based on Emailstatus using Statistics property of mailing class

Tags: 2011-sp1, audience-manager, outbound-email

I want to create a custom application to fetch all statics data of a mailing. I am using Tridion.AudienceManagement.API for this purpose. I am able to get all  information except how to get all contacts based on Emailstatus using Statistics property of  mailing class means I want the list of contacts which has status **delivered email** etc. Kindly suggest how to get this info.

Comment: What have you tried? It should be as simple as setting the properties on ContactFilter.Statistics; is that not working for you?

Comment: Thanks peter for giving me hint ContactFilter.Statistics is working solution.

Comment: oh okay -- I thought you were already using that class, but I see now that you referenced the Statistics property on a Mailing and not on the ContactFilter. I've added this as an answer for future prosperity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the various property on the ContactFilter.Statistics property, such as MailingUri and EmailStatus.